# Applying a sliding average window for each rows of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot, sliding-window

I have a matrix of 9 rows and 2000 columns. I would like to apply a sliding average window from the `library(caTools)`. The function is called `runmean`. I have used this function several times in the past, but I don't know how I can apply it for every rows of my matrix ?

My matrix is available here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/nep9uo346i69cts/foos.txt

```
x = read.table("foos.txt", row.names=1)
m = as.matrix(x)
mm=t(m)
matplot(mm, type="l")
```

I would like to smooth the lines of my plot (below), hence the sliding window. Thanks for all you feedback.

[image]

Comment: `runmean(mm,k=2)` or `runmean(t(mm),k=2)` ? (k= is the width of your window.)

Comment: or using `rollapply(mm, width=2, FUN=mean)` from zoo package.

Answer (score 0):

That does the trick. Thanks for your comments.

```
k = 20
mmean = runmean(mm, k)

matplot(mmean, type="l", lwd=3, lty=1)
```

[image]